# problem in installation stuck.... Might be a rookie question please guide

Tags: ros, rosinstall, setup.sh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI...
I am trying to install the ROS complete desktop environment.... in mac osx lion.

```
Log for python26 is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_python26/python26/main.log
To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>
[ rosmake ] rosdep install failed: rosdep script failed with stderr 
{{{
Error: Target org.macports.destroot returned: shell command failed (see log for details)
Error: Unable to upgrade port: 1
Error: Unable to execute port: upgrade python26 failed

}}}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/rosinstall", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('rosinstall==0.5.22', 'rosinstall')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 489, in run_script
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1214, in run_script
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.22-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 679, in <module>
    
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.22-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 670, in rosinstall_main
    
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 511, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'source /Users/rajeshmedampudi/ros/setup.sh && rosmake ros ros_comm --rosdep-install' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Please help or guide me in the right path... i am having a tough time to find any material....
thank you.....

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11817/problem-in-installation-stuck....-might-be-a-rookie-question-please-guide./) by [medampudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1324/medampudi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2011-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For ROS on mac and Lion especially I would recommend you work with homebrew, and William has a decent outline of this right [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/OSX/Homebrew) . If you decide to stick to macports though, you might want to check your python path issues

---

Originally posted by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) with karma: 1295 on 2011-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [medampudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1324/medampudi/) on 2011-11-07**:
Thanks... For the information... yours will be awarded the answer .... by the way i installed with Macports itself... had a seen a few suggestions. for working on it. out... will explain as an answer.